# C# / WPF WebBrowser does not load one site

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, yandex

`WebBrowser` does not load site `https://market.yandex.ru`. Process has stopped work.

```
wb.Navigate (@"https://market.yandex.ru");
```

XAML:

```
<WebBrowser x:Name="wb"></WebBrowser>
```

Google and other sites load well. Why does it happen?
I tied to change emulation mode (from IE11 to IE10 and IE9), it did not help.

My be there is same way with 3rd party libraries?

Answer (score 0):

.Net WebBrowser is really not good. I found `OpenQA.Selenium` library. It provide drivers to operate all browsers.

Unfortunelly, Microsoft does not know how to build good web browser yet.